# SCRIPT5009: 'Recaptcha' is undefined

Tags: c#, security, internet-explorer, recaptcha

I'm using Google's Recaptcha in my asp.net MVC page and its been working fine up until now.

Everything works fine in chrome and Firefox but internet explorer.... well. I get this error in my debugger:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Recaptcha' is undefined 
reload?c=03...., line 1 character 1
```

this happens every time i submit my form on the page. The result gives a Recaptcha display box but no security code in it.

are there any solutions to this? 
thanks in advance
EDIT: this occurs in ie version 9

Comment: pls mention which version of IE. Also does this happen with all version of IE ?

Comment: version is ie9 (the actual version not an emulator)

Comment: @kapetanios have you resolved this issue? I get the "SCRIPT5009: 'Recaptcha' is undefined" in IE9, when trying to load the reCaptcha dynamically.

Comment: @colecmc I did resolve it. Let me remember how and I'll get back to you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035402/c-sharp-mvc3-website-loaded-over-https-cannot-load-recaptcha-security-code-chr

Comment: From memory I replaced the mvc captcha control with straight JavaScript and it worked. Let me know if it works for u

Comment: My issue was slightly different, even though the error was the same. Thanks.